# My local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes. i can't push to heroku

Tags: git, heroku

i can't deploy my app to heroku. multiple apps in git remote. how can i fix this problem?

```
    Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
    Usage: --remote origin
    or: --app arcane-scrubland-65909
    Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git 
    remotes.
    Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this 
    command against.
    Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
    Heroku remotes in repo:
    secure-badlands-61058 (heroku)
    arcane-scrubland-65909 (origin)
```

Comment: we are missing some context here... what is the git command you performed?

Comment: git push heroku master. i deleted the app initially, created a new one using heroku-create  so i had to set a new remote url..

Comment: Have you tried this ```git push heroku master --app <app-name>``` as the error log suggests?

Comment: yes i have. still not working

Comment: check you .git/config and keep the one needed.

Answer (score 3):

### -> git push heroku master
#I run this in my app and I got the error message for the app.

I check the "config" file under the "./git/"
It IS showing 2 Apps:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://git.heroku.com/yinow.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
**# [remote "heroku"]
#   url = https://git.heroku.com/yinow.git
#   fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/heroku/***
```

I comment out the "heroku" one as above, and run the push command again like this:

-> git push origin master

and the problem gone!